Sphinx is throwing some indentation errors, and I cannot figure out how to fix them
These are the errors I am getting from Sphinx:

Unexpected indentation:
[{
"resource": "/c:/Users/User/Documents/GitHub/MIMIC/mimic/model_simulate/base_model.py",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#5",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Unexpected indentation.",
"source": "sphinx",
"startLineNumber": 46,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 47,
"endColumn": 1
}]
Definition list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent:
[{
"resource": "/c:/Users/User/Documents/GitHub/MIMIC/mimic/model_simulate/base_model.py",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#5",
"severity": 4,
"message": "Definition list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.",
"source": "sphinx",
"startLineNumber": 44,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 45,
"endColumn": 1
}]
Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent:
[{
"resource": "/c:/Users/User/Documents/GitHub/MIMIC/mimic/model_simulate/base_model.py",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#5",
"severity": 4,
"message": "Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.",
"source": "sphinx",
"startLineNumber": 47,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 48,
"endColumn": 1
}]

and this is the docstring:
    """
    Abstract base class for creating and managing simulation models.

    This class serves as a foundation for any type of model that requires
    managing data, parameters, and basic I/O operations. It defines a
    common interface for parameter handling, data simulation, and data
    persistence.

    Attributes:
        data (np.ndarray | None): Holds the output data generated by the model's simulation.
            This could be None if the model has not yet produced any data.
        model (object | None): A generic placeholder for the specific simulation model instance.
            This attribute should be overridden in subclasses with an actual
            model representation.
        parameters (dict | None): A dictionary containing the parameters that control the model's
            behavior. Parameters should be defined in subclasses or set through
            the provided methods.

    Abstract Methods:
        set_parameters(self): Should be implemented by subclasses to define how model parameters
            are set or updated.
        simulate(self): Should be implemented by subclasses to define the model's simulation process
            based on the set parameters.

    Methods:
        check_params(self, params, sim_type): Checks provided parameters against required ones for a
            given simulation type, applying default values if necessary.
        read_parameters(self, filepath): Reads model parameters from a specified JSON file and updates
            the model's parameters accordingly.
        save_parameters(self, filepath, parameters=None): Saves the model's current parameters to a
            JSON file. Optionally, a specific set of parameters can be provided to save instead.
        print_parameters(self, precision=2): Prints the current set of model parameters to the console,
            formatting numpy arrays with specified precision.
        save_data(self, filename, data=None): Saves the model's generated data to a CSV file. Optionally,
            specific data can be provided to save instead.
        load_data(self, filename): Loads data from a specified CSV file into the model's `data` attribute.
        _custom_array_to_string(self, array, precision=2): Converts a numpy array to a string representation
            with specified precision.
        update_attributes(self): Updates class attributes based on the current parameters dictionary.
    """

The docstring starts at line 10.
Help!

Paste the exact source, not an annotated version. Also paste the exact error messages.

How to debug:

Copy paste the offending docstring content into a text editor.
Save and translate with rst2html. (Translate with Sphinx, if the source contains Sphinx-extensions to standard reStructuredText.)

The error messages point to the relevant lines in your source document.
Fix indentation of line 35:
     save_data(self, filename, data=None): Saves the model's generated data to a CSV file. Optionally,
         specific data can be provided to save instead.
     load_data(self, filename): Loads data from a specified CSV file into the model's `data` attribute.
-    _custom_array_to_string(self, array, precision=2): Converts a numpy array to a string representation
+        _custom_array_to_string(self, array, precision=2): Converts a numpy array to a string representation
         with specified precision.
     update_attributes(self): Updates class attributes based on the current parameters dictionary.

Make the last line a definition list item:
     load_data(self, filename): Loads data from a specified CSV file into the model's `data` attribute.
     _custom_array_to_string(self, array, precision=2): Converts a numpy array to a string representation
         with specified precision.
-    update_attributes(self): Updates class attributes based on the current parameters dictionary.
+    update_attributes(self):
+        Updates class attributes based on the current parameters dictionary.

You may also want to fix all other definition list entries with a newline after the definition term and properly indented description (cf. definition lists).
